# Laravel-echo with socket.io on production still got net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: redis, socket.io, laravel-echo

I tried running Laravel-echo with redis driver on the server, but always got a net error: ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT even though I had allowed inbound TPC connections on the firewall, I was confused besides what TCP firewall I should do.

Comment: Do you have a solution on your problem